# Trouble understanding how to handle errors and continue with subscription with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this concept. I have 2 forms which can be handled by the same xhr call. So I'm sending the form submissions through a common stream and switching to an xhr call. I'm attempting to use catchError to handle any 500s, which DOES work (the .publish(error) call puts up a dialog w/ the error message), but then the subscription immediately completes! I thought this would continuously take input from the search$ stream until I called `this.search$.complete()` (which happens on componentDestroy). What am I missing about 'catch and continue listening' with RXJS?

```
  this.search$.pipe(
      tap(() => this.pending = true),
      switchMap(criteria => this._dealer.search(criteria)),
      catchError(ErrorNotifierService.catchResponseErrorAsObservable)
    ).subscribe(response => {
      this.pending = false;
      if (ErrorNotifierService.isCaughtError(response)) {
        this._error.publish(ErrorNotifierService.getErrorNotification(response.error));
      } else {
        this.dsSearchResults.data = response;
      }
    }, () => console.log('subscribe errored'), () => console.log('subscribe completed?'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `catchError` into the `switchMap` call as you want to "hide" the error from the switched observable already. This can be done simply by nesting it:

```js
this.search$.pipe(
  tap(() => this.pending = true),
  switchMap(criteria => this._dealer.search(criteria)
    .pipe(catchError(ErrorNotifierService.catchResponseErrorAsObservable))
  )
).subscribe(…);
```

The problem with your code is that in your case `switchMap` will switch to an observable emitting the error, which ends the subscription. We want to map this error to an emission *before* we switch to that observable so that the resulting stream never even sees an error.

You can find a runnable, online example of your code [here](https://rxviz.com/v/7Ja5XE4J) and the fixed example [here](https://rxviz.com/v/b8mA7Nv8).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the expanded explanation of why. Gonna take a bit to wrap my head around it but I changed my application to match your example and it worked exactly as expected.

Comment: Basically what switchMap does is everytime it receives a value, it subscribes to the inner observable and forwards those emissions. If the previous inner subscription hasn't finished when a new value comes along, it unsubscribes from it first. By having catchError outside of this, this inner subscription will error, which causes switchMap to forward it to the outer one. Once an observable errored, it can no longer emit. By moving catchError inside, it's only the inner observable that can no longer emit, but the outer one still can, allowing the entire stream to keep functioning.